# VB script to update links in a workbook with data from another excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I can manually update the link with the "edit links" option under the Data menu item but I'm attempting to update the link with a button. Here's what I have thus far but I'm getting stuck on the `updatelink` line in the script below:

```
Sub GetLinks()

    Dim Response As Integer, PASSWORD As String
    Response = MsgBox(prompt:="UPDATE NOW?", Buttons:=vbYesNo)

        If Response = vbYes Then        
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("456")
            ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:="c:\activityreportdatabase.xlsx", Type:=xlExcelLinks
            ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
            ActiveSheet.Protect ("456")
        Else
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is `activityreportdatabase.xlsx` really in the root directory?

Comment: What specifically does *I'm getting stuck* mean? You've not explained a problem, or asked a question that can be answered.

Comment: The scripts stops running and debug takes me to the line noted.

Comment: Chris Neilson, yes the file is in that location.

Comment: Ken, are you familiar with what I am trying to accomplish? Is this in your wheelhouse? I am attempting to use a button with a script which will update the links with data from a file stored in the location noted. The script stops running at the line of code with the location\file name of the file that has the data I need.